# Using $ as delimiter in StringTemplate from ANTRL rewriter grammars

Tags: antlr, antlr3, stringtemplate

I'm trying to write an ANTLR3 grammar that generates HTML output using StringTemplate. To avoid having to escape all the HTML tags in the template rules (e.g. `\<p\><variable>\</p\>`), I'd prefer to use dollar as the delimiter for StringTemplate (e.g. `<p>$variable$</p>`).

While the latter seems to be the default when StringTemplate is used on its own, the parser code generated by ANTRL always uses `AngleBracketTemplateLexer` when initializing StringTemplate.

How can I get ANTLR to generate code using `DefaultTemplateLexer` (i.e. the variant that uses dollar as the delimiter)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the `DefaultTemplateLexer.class` in the `StringTemplateGroup` like this:

```
StringTemplateGroup group = new StringTemplateGroup(reader, 
                                                    DefaultTemplateLexer.class);
```